# Can't add to a RichTextBox from another class?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a main form called *FormMain*.
*FormMain* has a RichTextBox inside of it called *mainConsole*.
I created a method inside of *FormMain*:

```
public void ConsoleAdd(String text)
{
    mainConsole.AppendText(text);
    mainConsole.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I changed the property Modifiers of *mainConsole* to Public.

Now in another class I wrote this in a button control:

```
FormMain fMain = new FormMain();
fMain.ConsoleAdd("Success!");
```

But it doesn't work. There is no exception raised, and there is no text added either.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is mainConsole ?

Comment: A richtextbox @MaheshChavda

Comment: Does `FormMain` already exist when the button control does its call to `ConsoleAdd()`? I'm guessing that instead of creating a new `FormMain`, you're wanting to use the one that currently exists.

Comment: I suspect you have an _existing_ form that you expect the code in the other form's button to reference.  The code is creating a _new_ form - you need to pass the second form a reference to the first form in order to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is that you call `ConsoleAdd` on the wrong reference. It seems like you create a new reference of `FormMain` and call `ConsoleAdd` on this one. If you call

```
fMain.Show();
```

you would see a second window pop-up with the text in the RichTextBox. You have to pass the reference to the correct `FormMain` to the function trying to call `ConsoleAdd` or use a Singleton.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I now have a better understanding of how instances work!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

In the *FormMain* I added this code:

```
static FormMain instance;
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    instance = this;
}     
public static FormMain Instance
{
    get
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And in the other class I called the method like this:

```
FormMain fMain = FormMain.Instance;
fMain.ConsoleAdd("Success!");
```

Thanks for the answers everybody!

Comment: This construct is a singleton ;)